# Spring Restful Array object as input

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, rest, spring-mvc

I am reading empty data in server side. Please help.

my java script code snip:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "services/save",
    data: items,
    success: saveSuccess
});
```

JSON data:

```
[{"id":"SRMS12345","status":"backlog","text":"Make a new Dashboard","content":"New content","tags":"SRMS12345,05-Jul-16","color":"#ffcc66","resourceId":"A70729","className":""},{"id":"SRMS17147","status":"sit","text":"Prepare new release","content":"New content","tags":"SRMS17147,05-Apr-16","color":"#ff7878","resourceId":"A70729","className":""},{"id":"INC2311424","status":"pv","text":"One item added to the cart","content":"New content","tags":"INC2311424,06-Jun-16","color":"#96c443","resourceId":"C02153","className":""},{"id":"INC3215575","status":"uat","text":"Edit Item Price","content":"New content","tags":"INC3215575,02-Oct-16","color":"#96c443","resourceId":"A71787","className":""},{"id":"SRMS15645","status":"backlog","text":"Login 404 issue","content":"New content","tags":"SRMS15645,02-Aug-16","color":"#96c443","resourceId":0,"className":""}]
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Services {
    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public boolean saveTaskStatus(ArrayList<AssignmentVO> assignments) {
    System.out.println(assignments);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not telling Spring where is the data that you're sending.

You need to add *@RequestBody* to the assignments *parameter*, so Spring can know where the data is.

You can read this article. http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/014-post-json-to-spring-rest-webservice/

Comment: Thank You Reos, but after I added '@RequestMapping' like shown in the link, The request does not reach the method at all!!

 @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public boolean saveTaskStatus(@RequestBody ArrayList<AssignmentVO> assignments) {
  System.out.println(assignments);
  return true;
 }

Comment: Is there any trace in the log ? What http error status is returned to the client ? You can try the service first with a tool like Postman or Advance Rest Client.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working. Thanks to reos.
I had to add the following to get it work

1. @ResponseBody to method Parameter (Thank you reos)
2. add ContentType and dataType to Ajax call
3. Add JSON.stringify to ajax call. Ajax call does not stringify automatically

Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "POST",
    url: "services/save",
    data: JSON.stringify(items),
    success: saveSuccess
});
```